# Nexus oss 3.x upgrade plan if both versions are running on same server?

Tags: open-source, upgrade, nexus

How should we plan Nexus Oss 2.14.3 upgrade to Nexus Oss 3.2.1 if Version 2.14.3 and version 3.2.1 running on the same server??
Please share your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Use the upgrade instructions here:  http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference3/upgrading.html#upgrade-version-two-three  since they are both on the same server I'd recommend using the "File System Hard Linking" transfer method, that will be far faster than any other method.